# MySQL error message after creating table: #1146 - Table ''phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am very new to MySQL. I just created a new database, a table with seven fields, and I inserted some data. In phpmyadmin, I try to select the "Browse" tab at the top, but I get a red error message that says:

```
SELECT `prefs` FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_table_uiprefs`  
WHERE `username` = 'root'  
AND `db_name` = 'tutorials'  
AND `table_name` = 'users'
```

As well as:

`1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs' doesn't exist`

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you dropped a phpmyadmin table at some point. Try recreating it from the "SQL" or "Query" tab (not sure what's it's called nowadays):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_uiprefs` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `prefs` text NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Tables'' UI preferences'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

You can find all tables that a complete phpmyadmin installation should have in the [examples/create_tables.sql](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/examples/create_tables.sql) file.

Comment: I tried that to my best ability, I made have done something wrong. I pasted that text into the SQL tab but the problem didn't go away. I just created the table again. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the create_tables.sql inside the examples/ folder on phpMyAdmin to create the tables needed for the advanced features.

Create table by imorting the create_tables.sql file, you should go to the import tab on phpmyadmin and select that file, and click on Go button.

Now open xampp/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php file and check in line no. 36-47 like pma_bookmark and other with pma_ . Replace pma__bookmark (__ this is double underscore). Save and then browser the table without any issue.